# PHP mysql fetch row code to find variable value within another table item

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm not a programming person, but had some in the distant past.
My website person just emigrated and I need to make a small change in the following PHP code here myself. Its not worthwhile to recruit a developer for this.

Its just the ""**mysql_fetch_row** line below thats relevant.

Currently this returns all rows in the table where the OWNER fields are complete match.
I need to change this to match where the OWNER contents equals any part of the table field, where each item contained there are sepereated in CSV fashion.

For example, I need to find an owner3 input match within the field that contains owner1,owner2,owner3,owner4 etc

```
$rs = mysql_query("select
    type,
    ref,
    date,
    owner   

    from documents where account=" . quote($currentaccount) . " and owner=" .      quote($owner) . " and type like 'CR%' order by entered desc");
echo '<table class="data" width="97%">';
while ($r = mysql_fetch_row($rs))
{
    $i = 0;
    echo '<tr>';

    $type = $r[$i++];
    echo '<td>';
    echo esc($type);
    echo '</td>';

    $ref = $r[$i++];
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<a href="download.php?type=' . escurl($type) . '&ref=' . escurl($ref) . '">' .  esc($ref) . '</a>';
    echo '</td>';

    $s = $r[$i++];
    echo '<td>';
    echo strdate($s);
    echo '</td>';

    $s = $r[$i++];
    echo '<td align="right">';
    echo blankzero($s);
    echo '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

require '../inc/end.php';
```

Comment: did u see csv format in database field? can you show a sample row

Answer (score 0):

change the SQL to read..

```
and owner LIKE ".quote("%".$owner."%")."
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! That worked perfectly. Much appreciated. If ever in Ireland, buy you a pint. Liam

Comment: :) No Problem. If this answer was usefull to you please mark the question as resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Full Text Search or INSTR.

```
and `owner` LIKE '%" . quote($owner) . "%'
```

or

```
and INSTR(`owner`, '" . quote($owner) . "')
```

The first will be faster for rows with fulltext indexing.